# Adding with carry on PIC16 (or similar)

Tags: assembly, pic

There is no "add with carry" instruction on PIC 16. But what if I had to add larger data quantity than just a byte? All the Web resources and Microchip application notes I've found suggest something like:

```
MOVF   LSB_A, w
ADDWF  LSB_B

MOVF   MSB_A, w
BTFSC  STATUS, C
INCFSZ MSB_A, w
ADDWF  MSB_B
```

but the code above will just not work. I mean the 16-bit result will be correct, but the carry won't be set properly, so you can't just expand the computational range by repeating the second part of the code above. Am I right so far?

Below is my implementation of addition with carry:

```
MOVF    BYTE1, w
BTFSC   STATUS, C
ADDLW   1
RLF     TEMP       ; save the carry
ADDWF   BYTE2
BTFSS   STATUS, C
RRF     TEMP       ; restore the carry (from the first addition)
```

You can use plain addition for the least significant byte or clear the carry before using a sequence of additions with carry.
I guess it works, but are there more effective solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microchip's Code Module Library (CML) gives the following snippet for 16-bit addition, which does seem to cope with the overflow situation you describe (too large for a comment so I hope you'll forgive me posting as an answer) :

```
    ; Snippet:  16-bit  A+B
    ;
    ; Inputs:   A_high, A_low, B_high, B_low
    ; Outputs:  RES_high, RES_low
    movf    A_low, W
    addwf   B_low, W
    movwf   RES_low             ; Result in RES_low

    movlw   0x00                ; Clear W
    btfsc   STATUS, C
    movlw   0x01                ; C=1, carry present.  Set W to add 1 to high bytes.
                                ; C=0, there was no carry from low byte to high byte

    addwf   A_high, W           ; Add A_high to W (either 0, or 1 if carry)
    btfsc   STATUS, C           ; Check for o/f when adding low carry
    goto    early_overflow      ;   if don't check here, A_high = 0xFF will miss high byte carry
    addwf   B_high, W           ; Add B_high to above
    movwf   RES_high            ; Result in RES_high

    btfss   STATUS, C           ; Check whole 16-bit addition for carry
    goto    end_add16           ; C=0, result valid      
    goto    overflow            ; C=1, result overflowed

early_overflow:
    addwf   B_high, W           ; Add B_high to A_high + carry
    movwf   RES_high            ; Result in RES_high

overflow:

    ; Can place code here to handle
    ; what to do in case result overflowed.

end_add16:                      ; end of snippet
```